# Piping ffmpeg output into ffplay stdin with boost

Tags: c++, c, boost, ffmpeg, pipe

I'm trying to pipe the output of an ffmpeg process into an ffplay process (Sort of like a playback). My problem is the following: If I copy the output character by character (by character I mean `char`) it works correctly, other than it consuming a whole lot of cpu power. However when I try to pipe chunks into it (by using a buffer), ffplay for some reason doesn't even recognize the input.

```cpp
bp::ipstream iso;
bp::ipstream ise;
bp::opstream in;
    
bp::child ffmpeg(bp::search_path("ffmpeg"), bp::args({"-loglevel", "quiet", "-f", "pulse", "-i", "default", "-f", "wav", "-bitexact", "-nostdin", "-"}), bp::std_out > iso, bp::std_err > ise);
bp::child ffplay(bp::search_path("ffplay"), bp::args({"-loglevel", "verbose", "-nodisp", "-f", "wav", "-i", "-"}), bp::std_in < in, bp::std_out > bp::null);
```

Here are the 2 code snippets for comparison:

Here it is copying `char` by `char`

```cpp
while(ffmpeg.running()) {
    char c;
    c = iso.get();
    in << c;
}
```

And here it is copying with the help of a buffer

```cpp
char buffer[1024];
while(ffmpeg.running()) {
    iso.get(buffer, 1024);
    in << buffer;
}
```

I can provide ffplay output if necessary, however I didn't see any errors or things like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instaed of doing the chore manually, you can just attach the same pipes:

```
bp::child ffmpeg(
    pg, bp::search_path(prod.cmd), bp::args(prod.args),
    bp::std_out > iso,
    bp::std_err > ise
);

bp::child ffplay(
    pg, bp::search_path(cons.cmd), bp::args(cons.args),
    (bp::std_in < iso)
    //, (bp::std_out> bp::null)
);
```

That will do what you expect. THis also implies you don't choose `ipstream`/`opstream`, because the role is both:

```
//bp::pstream iso, ise, in;
bp::pipe iso, ise, in;
```

Both work, but you probably don't need the complexity of the stream objects. In fact you can use the async versions, and it will still behave the same (but give you more options/control for async running):

[image]

### Live Online Demo

With obviously replaced/simplified commands for the producer/consumer processes:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0e986256a1bf8c80)**

```
#include <boost/process.hpp>

namespace bp = boost::process;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
using boost::system::error_code;

int main() {
    //bp::pstream iso, ise, in;
    bp::pipe iso, ise, in;
    //boost::asio::io_context io;
    //bp::async_pipe iso(io), ise(io), in(io);
    bp::group pg;

    struct { std::string cmd; std::vector<std::string> args; } tasks[] = {
#if 1
         { "bash", { "-c", "echo 'hello world'"} },
         { "rev", {} },
#else
         { "ffmpeg", {"-loglevel", "quiet", "-f", "pulse", "-i", "default", "-f", "wav", /*"-bitexact",*/ "-nostdin", "-"} },
         { "ffplay", {"-loglevel", "verbose", "-nodisp", "-f", "wav", "-i", "-"} },
#endif
    };

    auto& [prod, cons] = tasks;

    bp::child ffmpeg(
        pg, bp::search_path(prod.cmd), bp::args(prod.args),
        bp::std_out > iso,
        bp::std_err > ise
    );

    bp::child ffplay(
        pg, bp::search_path(cons.cmd), bp::args(cons.args),
        (bp::std_in < iso)
        //, (bp::std_out> bp::null)
    );

    if (!pg.wait_for(4s))
        pg.terminate();
}
```

Prints the reverse of "hello world" as expected:

```
dlrow olleh
```

### Doing The Nasty

Just to show, here's how you could manually do the IO pump.

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1897fcc273db974c)**

```
#include <boost/process.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace bp = boost::process;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
using boost::system::error_code;

int main() {
    //bp::pstream iso, ise, in;
    //bp::pipe iso, ise, in;
    boost::asio::io_context io;
    bp::async_pipe iso(io), ise(io), in(io);
    bp::group pg;

    struct { std::string cmd; std::vector<std::string> args; } tasks[] = {
#if 1
         { "bash", { "-c", "echo -e 'hello world\\nYOHOHO\\nMOHOHO\\n'"} },
         { "xxd", {} },
#else
         { "ffmpeg", {"-loglevel", "quiet", "-f", "pulse", "-i", "default", "-f", "wav", /*"-bitexact",*/ "-nostdin", "-"} },
         { "ffplay", {"-loglevel", "verbose", "-nodisp", "-f", "wav", "-i", "-"} },
#endif
    };

    auto& [prod, cons] = tasks;

    bp::child ffmpeg(
        io, pg, bp::search_path(prod.cmd), bp::args(prod.args),
        bp::std_out > iso,
        bp::std_err > ise
    );

    bp::child ffplay(
        io, pg, bp::search_path(cons.cmd), bp::args(cons.args),
        (bp::std_in < in)
        //, (bp::std_out> bp::null)
    );

    std::function<void()> stream_pump;
    stream_pump = [&, buf=std::vector<char>(1024)]() mutable {
      boost::asio::async_read(iso, boost::asio::buffer(buf), [&](error_code ec, size_t const nread) {
        bool const eof = (ec == boost::asio::error::eof);
        std::cerr << "nread: " << nread << " (eof:" << eof << ")\n";
        if (ec && !eof)
          std::cerr << "async_read: " << ec.message() << " (" << nread << ")\n";
        else
          boost::asio::async_write(in, boost::asio::buffer(buf, nread),
            [=,&in,&stream_pump](error_code ec, size_t /*nwritten*/) {
              if (ec || eof) {
                std::cerr << "Closing in\n";
                in.close();
              }
              else
                stream_pump(); // continue the pump
          });
      });
    };

    stream_pump(); // prime the pump

    auto nhandlers = io.run_for(4s);
    std::cerr << "Handlers executed: " << nhandlers << "\n";
    ffmpeg.terminate();

    if (ffplay.running())
        ffplay.wait_for(1s);

    if (ffplay.running())
        pg.terminate();
}
```

Prints

```
nread: 27 (eof:1)
Closing in
Handlers executed: 6
```

And the consumer child process stdout contains

```
00000000: 6865 6c6c 6f20 776f 726c 640a 594f 484f  hello world.YOHO
00000010: 484f 0a4d 4f48 4f48 4f0a 0a              HO.MOHOHO..
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Once I have time I'll try out all of your solutions, and decide which is the best. The reason for reading in chunks is because I'll want to route the data through the network. But this of course isn't in the scope of this question.

Comment: @botiapa The "Doing The Nasty" section already shows how to do it. Just replace `in` with a `boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket` or even your [`boost::beast::websocket::tcp_stream`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/using_websocket.html). Anything that models [`AsyncWriteStream`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/AsyncWriteStream.html) obviously.

Comment: @moi Sure http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9cf95c8597c7fd50 - somehow Coliru doesn't include Boost Process at the time of writing ...